# How to install RealVNC Server on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS?

Tags: vnc, ubuntu

I would like to install RealVNC on Ubuntu Mate as it would have installed on Raspbian Jessie.

Answer (score 1):

These answers are correct but incomplete. To get the native Raspbian experience, e.g. with a panel icon for the service that expands into an information window, you must also manually enable the service after installing.

1. Download the server `.deb` package from https://www.realvnc.com/en/download/vnc/raspberrypi/
2. Install using `sudo dpkg -i <path/to/file>` or by double-clicking to open with *gdebi*
3. From the command line, enable the correct service:

   - To access local session, use Service mode: `sudo systemctl enable vncserver-x11-serviced.service`
   - To access a virtual session, use Virtual mode: `sudo systemctl enable vncserver-virtuald.service`
4. Reboot or manually start the service using `sudo systemctl start <service>`

You will have to use a command line because there is no on/off switch for VNC in the Ubuntu MATE version of `raspi-config` (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Through RealVNC packages are form the Debian repo, i suggest I'd suggest you install **gdebi** and then navigate it to the package for installation. Or you can use

> Desktop Sharing *(which is from the Software Center)*

or

> TightVNC (alternative)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the deb packages from here: https://www.realvnc.com/en/download/vnc/raspberrypi/

Extract the deb files (there's one for the server and viewer) from the downloaded tar.gz and install with:

```
sudo dpkg --install <deb_filename>
```

There's not guarantee it'll work though, since RealVNC only officially support Raspbian.